# How do I set the boundaries of the legend for a ListDensityPlot?

Tags: legending

I have a 3-d array imported from a text file. One dimension represents time, and the other two represent space. It's basically an array of 2-d arrays of temperature values. I want to plot these values in a ListDensityPlot using the manipulate command to change the time I'm looking at. I did this with the following command:

`Manipulate[
 ListDensityPlot[data[[x]], PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
  ColorFunction -> "Warm"], {x, 1, Length[data] - 1}]`

where "data" is the variable containing the array.
The only problem (apart from it being a little slow) is that every time I move the slider, the range of the legend adjusts based on the values currently shown in the plot. This means that as you slide the bar from start to finish, the change in plot does not accurately represent the data because the scale changes.

How do I make the scale stay the same?

Comment: Try fixing the plot range in ListDensityPlot and see what happens

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was very surprised to find that manually setting `PlotRange` to cover the entire data range doesn't work.  The legend and colorfunction both seem to pick out the range of the data set; so `PlotRange` can only be used to limit the range:

```
min = Min[data];
max = Max[data];
Manipulate[
 ListDensityPlot[data[[All, All, k]], ColorFunction -> "Warm", 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic, PlotRange -> {All, All, {min, max}}], {k,
   1, 51, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics] 
[image: Mathematica graphics]

One way around this behaviour is to use a custom `ColorFunction` that maps the data range to [0, 1], so that we can deactivate `ColorFunctionScaling`.  We can then create our own fixed legend using `BarLegend`.  Now everything works as intended:

```
colfunc = ColorData["Warm"][#/max] &;
leg = BarLegend[{colfunc, {min, max}}];
Manipulate[
 ListDensityPlot[data[[All, All, k]], ColorFunction -> colfunc, 
  PlotLegends -> leg, ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
  PlotRange -> All], {k, 1, 51, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: That did exactly what I wanted, thank you!